# Many to one ApexSql data diff Database Transfer

Tags: database, data-transfer

I have searched the answers and haven't found anything relating to the project I'm currently working on. If I've missed it if you could please link the URL it would be greatly appreciated.

Currently we have many sets in the field which run various applications to transfer field data to a master database. These applications were developed for different reason as different times and are currently sending only specific data. We now have a need to send all data. I was hoping to leverage ApexSQL, a product we already have, data diff to possibly transfer each infield servers net new row entries to the main database.

I was hoping to get some information from someone who may have already looked at this as a possibility or have implemented it in the past.

The extra fun aspect of this project is that it must fall under PCI compliance which I can figure out after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer only new entries, you have to synchronize the records that exist in your source (infield servers) and are "missing" in your destination (the main database). ApexSQL Data Diff can do this, but you have to select all records in the Missing tab for the specific tables and unselect all records in the Additional tab. If you leave the records selected inn the Additional tab, the records that exist in the main database but doesn't in the infield servers will be deleted, so you have to be careful

[image]

If you have [ApexSQL Diff API](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_diffapi.aspx), you can use SynchronizeMissingRows and all missing rows in the database will be synchronized